# Bitcoindの構築につきまして

Tags: c++, windows

プログラミング初歩の質問で申し訳ございません。
先日、windows10でUbuntuを用いて https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin をクローンし,bitcoindを作成しようとしたのですがmakeの段階で以下のようなエラーが発生し、makeすることができませんでした。

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o): relocat R_X86_64_32     against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared     object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:3690: recipe for target 'bitcoind' failed
```

質問内容が的を射ていないかもしれませんが、解決法並びに質問の改善についてご回答いただけますと幸いです。

追記:作業手順について（記憶の範囲で申し訳ありません）

1. MiNGW for 64を導入
2. Ubutuを導入
3. ```sh
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade
   sudo apt install build-essential libtool autotools-dev automake pkg-config bsdmainutils curl git
   ```
4. 上記のgitをクローン
5. boostlib1.6.0.tar.gzをインストール
6. Openssl 1.0.2oをインストール
7. berkeley db 4.8をインストール
8. bitcoinディレクトリで`./configure`(--enable-sharedでも同様です)
9. 同ディレクトリで`sudo make`←ここでエラーが発生しました

追記2
configureの最後に記載されていたオプションです

```
ptions used to compile and link:
  with wallet   = yes
  with gui / qt = no
  with zmq      = no
  with test     = yes
  with bench    = yes
  with upnp     = yes
  use asm       = yes
  debug enabled = no
  gprof enabled = no
  werror        = no

  target os     = linux
  build os      =

  CC            = gcc
  CFLAGS        = -g -O2
  CPPFLAGS      =  -DHAVE_BUILD_INFO -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
  CXX           = g++ -std=c++11
  CXXFLAGS      = -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wvla -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter
  LDFLAGS       =
  ARFLAGS       = cr
```

Comment: どのコンパイラを使って make しているかが重要そうです。作業手順をひとつずつ追記してくださいませんか？　できれば第三者が同じエラーを出せるようなものだと完璧です。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。詳細な範囲をおぼえていないので恐縮ですが。おおむねの流れを追記させていただきました。

Comment: 手順1か手順3の後において、WSL上でクロスコンパイラ (mingw-w64) への切り替えは行いましたか？　[build-windows.md](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-windows.md) で言う所の update-alternatives です。

Comment: はい、そのコマンドは入力したことを確認いたしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

target os が linux になっているのがおかしいです。今回は Windows 向けのクロスコンパイルをすることが目的なので、ここは windows になっているべきです。

おそらく、`bitcoin/depends` を `make` するときに `HOST=x86_64-w64-mingw32` を指定し忘れているのではないでしょうか？ 手順としては [build-windows.md](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/048ac8326b6952244f6e4453f4f8f6ab423eb926/doc/build-windows.md#building-for-64-bit-windows) に書かれている以下の部分です。

> Once the source code is ready the build steps are below.
>
> ```sh
> PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e 's/:\/mnt.*//g') # strip out problematic Windows %PATH% imported var
> cd depends
> make HOST=x86_64-w64-mingw32
> cd ..
> ./autogen.sh # not required when building from tarball
> CONFIG_SITE=$PWD/depends/x86_64-w64-mingw32/share/config.site ./configure --prefix=/
> make
> ```

### 補足1

2018年4月現在の build-windows.md に従って WSL でビルドするには、一点だけ修正が必要です。MinGW-w64 をアップデートするために Ubuntu Zesty の APT リポジトリを追加していますが、Zesty のサポート期限が既に切れているため現在の

```
"deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty universe"
```

では追加できません。古いリリースを配布している

```
"deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty universe"
```

を使うか、新しいリリースである

```
"deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful universe"
```

などを使う必要があります。

### 補足2

github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin の HEAD は、ビルドできないことがあります。安定したビルドがほしければ、適当な version tag を checkout すれば良いです。たとえば 2018 年 4 月現在の latest release である 0.16 をビルドするには、リポジトリを clone して `cd bitcoin` した後、

```
git checkout 0.16
```

とすればよいです。

Comment: 詳細な回答、本当にありがとうございます。初級的な質問で申し訳ないのですが、上記のcd dependsはdependsというディレクトリが存在しているはず…という事でしょうか。

Comment: はい。`git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git` をしたディレクトリに `bitcoin` というフォルダができ、その中に `depends` というフォルダができているはずです。

Comment: 確認できました、ありがとうございます。もしnekketsuuu様が実行していればでよろしいのですが、上記のdepends内でのmakeはエラーなしで実行されましたでしょうか。お手すきの際に回答いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: はい、私の環境ではエラーなしで実行されました（随分時間がかかりましたが……）

Comment: 重ね重ね質問してしまい申し訳ありません。/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpectedというエラーが発生してしまったのですが、原因などもしお分かりになりましたら、お教えいただけますでしょうか。

Comment: depends を make する部分でエラーが出たのでしょうか？　こちらでは再現できていないので何とも言えませんね……。一度 WSL Ubuntu をクリーン・インストールするところからやり直すくらいしか思いつきません。