# Bitcoin coreのwindows上での構築について

Tags: linux

初級な質問で申し訳ありません。
現在、ubuntuをもちいてBitcoin coreをコンパイルしようとしているのですが、途中で以下のエラーならびに類似のエラーが多く発生してしまい、makeすることができません。解決法等分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら、回答いただけますと幸いです。
構築手順などは、以前させていただいた質問および回答を参照いたしましたのでURLを貼らせていただきます。（もし閲覧数増加などの規約違反である場合はご指摘いただきましたら、記載に変更いたします）

> error: ‘recursive_mutex’ is not a member of ‘std’
>
> error: ‘std::unique_lock::mutex_type {aka class CCriticalSection}’ has no member named ‘lock’

以前させていただいた質問:[Bitcoindの構築につきまして](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43001/bitcoind%e3%81%ae%e6%a7%8b%e7%af%89%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%8d%e3%81%be%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[build-windows.md](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/24133b177a8555e8d16216d0f848b6707ed60b76/doc/build-windows.md) の `update-alternatives` で x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-**posix** を選択してください。

なお、ビルドをやり直すために一度 `bitcoin` フォルダで `make clean` をする必要があります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。最終的にmakeされたものの名前はbitcoindになりますでしょうか。

Comment: いくつかバイナリができ、その中には `src/bitcoind.exe` も含まれます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。makeおよびmake installは通ったのですが、bitcoindやbitcoin-cliがwhichでも見つからないのですが、もし思い当たる点等ございましたら、お暇な時にお教えいただけると幸いです。

Comment: 確かデフォルト設定のままだと PATH が通っていないので which では見つからなかったはずです。見つけるなら `find . -name 'bitcoin*'` などで分かります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。最後に1つだけお伺いしたいのですがbitcoindはinstall終了段階でコマンドとして使えるようになっておりますでしょうか。bitcoinディレクトリ内でbitcoindを行ってもcommand not foundとなってしまうので、尋ねさせていただきました。

Comment: command not found になるのは PATH の問題です。また今回は Windows 環境向けにクロスコンパイルしたので、実行するのは Windows 側からになります。build-windows.md に書かれている [Installation](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/4781813b56177f8cfc1bf3d4160f75f3ec15e7e2/doc/build-windows.md#installation) が参考になるかと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。先のInstallationの項やクロスコンパイルなどは初めて行うのでわからないことが多いですが、頑張ってみたいと思います。