# LinuxとwindowsのクロスコンパイルにおけるBitcoindについて

Tags: linux, windows

先日よりたびたび申し訳ございません。
現在windows10でWSLを用いてUbuntu内で https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin をクローンし、bitcoindを作成しようとしております。皆様からの回答をいただいたことで、ubuntu上でのbitcoindのmake installは成功いたしました。

今回の質問は、上記クロスコンパイルの成果物をwindowsで実行する方法、ならびにbitcoindのパス設定について、方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら回答いただけますと幸いです。

これまでに質問させていただいた項についてURLを掲載いたしますので、あわせてご確認いただけますと幸いです。

**関連質問**
[Bitcoindの構築につきまして](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43001/bitcoind%e3%81%ae%e6%a7%8b%e7%af%89%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%8d%e3%81%be%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6/43047?noredirect=1#comment44360_43047)
[Bitcoin coreのwindows上での構築について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43061/bitcoin-core%e3%81%aewindows%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ae%e6%a7%8b%e7%af%89%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6/43064?noredirect=1#comment44416_43064)

Comment: 過去質問と話が続いてる場合でも、必要最低限の情報は(新しい)質問に含めるようにしてください。`make install`はあくまでコンパイルしたシステム(今回ならUbuntu)上にインストールするための手順なので、クロスコンパイルでWindows向けのバイナリをコンパイルしたのであれば、成果物をWindowsにコピーして実行すればいいだけのように思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。質問を修正させていただきました。「成果物をwindowsにコピーして実行する」とのことですが、クロスコンパイルもなのですが、このようなコンパイルの経験がなく、その実行についてわからない状態です。差し支えなければ、その点についてご指導いただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

どの部分の知識が不足しているのかがよく解らないのですが、
Ubuntu で、bitcoind.exe のあるディレクトリで

```
cp bitcoind.exe /mnt/c/Users/ユーザ名/
```

(「ユーザ名」の部分は置き換えて下さい)
とすれば、Windows のエクスプローラーで見れば `C:\Users\ユーザ名\` に bitcoind.exe ができているはずです。

あとは、エクスプローラーでお好きなディレクトリに移動させて、実行すれば良いと思います。